# needs-restarting does not acknowledge the new kernel

Tags: centos7, kernel

Could somebody explain why my server has booted up using the latest kernel (v3.10.0-1127.10.1),
yet the **needs-restarting** app says I still need to reboot to the new kernel?

```
[user@domain ~]$ uname -r
3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64


[user@domain ~]$ needs-restarting -r
Core libraries or services have been updated:
  systemd -> 219-73.el7_8.6
  kernel -> 3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7

Reboot is required to ensure that your system benefits from these updates.

More information:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/27943
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what caused this issue, but I did a **yum history undo** to revert back to a time before my yum updated kernel/systemd files. I then removed the kernel RPM to make sure it didn't boot. Once that was done, I rebooted, did a fresh **yum update**, rebooted, and then everything was back to normal.

Weird Event....